# What does "wave somebody forward" mean?

Tags: meaning

> Run only after he/she has recognized you and waves you forward.

Does it  mean "to wave at somebody to come closer" or does it mean "to stick the hand forward and then wave at somebody"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means "indicates for you to *move forward*".  In that particular sentence it sounds like "forward" means "closer to him/her", at least from your perspective.

It's not clear why you would *run* in this context, though.  It might make more sense to say something like:

> **Approach** only after he has recognized you and waves you forward.

Answer (score 0):

She/he invited you to come closer.

Here are a description of a very popular meme

> He waves you forward as he puts his hand to his mouth and whispers, “it’s free real estate.”

and a link to the meme

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=rQkCH_C-7AM